# Lists... 0% error when installing netcat

Tags: netcat

I get this when I try and install netcat:

```
root@server:~# sudo apt-get install nc -y
root@server:~#  lists... 0%
root@server:~#
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The command you typed to install `netcat` is wrong. To install `netcat` type the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install netcat -y
```

Also, since you are logged in the terminal as root, you do not need sudo. Just typing the following would do the trick:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install netcat -y
```

Comment: I tried that it acts like its installing then at the end has this 

Reading package lists... Error!
Segmentation fault
root@server:~#


Also when i try nc localhost 5555 it says 

root@server:~# nc localhost 5555
-bash: nc: command not found
root@server:~#

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the new error